# Xcode / Swift Resize UIWebView on Keyboard Open

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

Ok, I have spent hours on this and am probably just missing it... but how can I resize a UIWebView when a textfield is clicked and opens the keyboard?

Right now I am listening to the keyboard, getting all the measurements to resize it, then resizing it on:

```
keyboardWillShow()
```

In the emulator it works exactly as expected, and then reverts back after showing a constraint error on a UIButtonBarStackView with a '.trailing' attribute. I assume this comes from the the keyboard, but am not sure...

Does anyone know how to fix this, or where to look?

I have seen several other questions about it and tried the other solutions without any luck.

Comment: I'll post the code later, it is on my virtual machine takes a little to get if you need it

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 answer: (altough webView is being deprecated, i recommend the use of wekKitView)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {

        webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHideß(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        // For some reason adding inset in keyboardWillShow is animated by itself but removing is not, that's why we have to use animateWithDuration here
        self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) using this Library and try.

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```